# Clean uninstall TeamCity

Tags: teamcity

I tried to uninstall TeamCity (to make a clean install), following 
[this article](https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000573864-How-to-uninstall-TeamCity-).

I tried to remove (at once) `~/.BuildServer`, `TeamCity` and postgresql entries (drop's, remove, purge).

It had no effect, and instead of a clean startup I always get recovery. I cannot find any file/folder connected to TeamCity anymore.

How do I remove TeamCity so I can make clean install?

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

TeamCity configuration is stored within the data directory which can be in any arbitrarily selected location on the file system. If the data directory path pointing to an existing data directory, you will get a recovery instead of the clean install.
Data directory can be specified either in `TEAMCITY_DATA_PATH` environment variable or in `<TeamCity home directory>/conf/teamcity-startup.properties` file. Check those and see if there is an existing data directory at the path specified there.